# Redis interface of socket.io-emitter behaves differently on localhost and heroku+rediscloud

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, redis, socket.io

I'm using socket.io-emitter to push data to clients from my node app. On heroku I use (trying to) the 'rediscloud' addon to initialize the emitter. I'm using the same instance for my own key/value storage purposes.

The socket.io-emitter is initialized like below, which is different from the examples on its [github repo](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-emitter/blob/master/test/index.js#L61), but documented as valid:

```
var emitterRedisClient = redis.createClient(port, hostname, 
        {no_ready_check: true, return_buffers: true});
if (config.auth !== null) {
  emitterRedisClient.auth(config.auth.split(':')[1]);
}

var ioe = require('socket.io-emitter');
var emitter = ioe(emitterRedisClient);
```

And later somewhere:

```
emitter.to(clientSocketId).emit('update', data);
```

**^^^ This is the part that doesn't work.** On debug, I found that `emitter.to().emit()` uses `redis.publish` and receiving a callback from publish gives:

`{err: null, reply: 0}` using redis cloud on Heroku and doesn't send the data
`{err: null, reply: 1}` using local redis on localhost and sends the data

In case it helps, I use this in combination with the `socket.io-redis` adapter for the socket.io instance. That's initialized like this:

```
var pub = redis.createClient(port, hostname, {no_ready_check: true});
var sub = redis.createClient(port, hostname, {no_ready_check: true, detect_buffers: true});
if (config.auth !== null) {
  pub.auth(config.auth.split(':')[1]);
  sub.auth(config.auth.split(':')[1]);
}

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app); // where app is a restify server

io.adapter(redisAdapter({
  pubClient: pub,
  subCliend: sub
}));
```

Comment: Did you verify that your code actually succeeds opening a connection? The 'no_ready_check' will probably hide any errors until the connection is actually used.

Comment: Yes, the connection works. I tried a `emitterRedisClient.set('key', 'test')` and it works.

Comment: Understood. To get to the bottom of this I'd like to ask you to open a ticket directly with our helpdesk by sending an email to `support@redislabs.com`. Please include your account ID (i.e. displayed under `Account Info` in the Redis Cloud dashboard) and feel free to skip the message's body - just introduce yourself and include a link to this question and the team will help you get this sorted out.

Comment: Turns out the problem was a typo (it's there is the sample code above too). This is very embarrassing. But thanks for your time @ItamarHaber

Comment: My pleasure entirely. I'm glad that you found the typo!